# How to create many to many relationship between models in loopback?

Tags: node.js, many-to-many, loopbackjs

I might be missing something obvious here but have spent hours on this and unable to find a solution.

Suppose I have an employee model

```
"properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  };
```

and its child model

```
"properties": {
    "Code": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "Desc": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  }
```

How do I create a many to many relationship between them?

Answer (score 0):

You can add accepted properties passing accepts fields to remoteMethod options.
Read this page in the [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods).

```
module.exports = function(Task) {
    fs.readdir(PATH_PROCESS+PATH_API, (err, o) => {
        for(var c in o){
            var i = o[c];
            Task[i] = require(PATH_PROCESS+i+".js").lpb;
            Task.remoteMethod(
                i, {
                    http: {path: ('/'+i), verb: 'post'},
                    returns: {arg: 'result', type: 'object'},
                    accepts: [
                      {arg: 'params', type: 'object', required: true, http: {source: 'body'},
                        description: (i+' params.')}
                    ]
                }
            );
        }
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how your code creata a many-to-many relationship between models here

Comment: If i've understaned well, you can export also the parameters on module.exports.params and import them wherever you need to relate a module to another one.

Comment: That will embed one model attribute to another, it won't create a many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations):

> A hasManyThrough relation sets up a many-to-many connection with another model. This relation indicates that the declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another model by proceeding through a third model.

Use slc loopback:relation command to create relations between models. Don't forget to add through model when prompted (also explained in docs).

After you create relation between your models you will have to synchronize your changes with database using [automigrate()](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+a+database+schema+from+models#Creatingadatabaseschemafrommodels-Auto-migrate) or [autoupdate()](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+a+database+schema+from+models#Creatingadatabaseschemafrommodels-Auto-update).

Be careful when using automigrate because it will create or re-create your database which means that you can potentially loose your data.

Comment: `hasManyThrough` still checks for the child table values to be unique. It still wants me to set up a  unique role every time which goes against the principle of many to many. Is there a working example of many to many relationship via loopback? I am okay to have another table just to store the many to many relation?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I am not sure that I understand this " It still wants me to set up a unique role every time", can you explain please? Also, have you tried patients - physicians example from the docs?

Comment: Sorry, haven't tried that yet. Can you share the link?

Comment: Oh I think Employee-UserRole is similar right? and it is not working for me

Comment: The second model in your question is UserRole right? You need to have third model in between. Create EmployeeUserRole model and use it as through model. This is equivalent to "Appointment" model from the docs.

Comment: I did that. it still gives error if the same User Role is attached to another employee.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103298/discussion-between-a-z-and-gurvinder372).